# how to do multiple tracking like a series of pages one after another?

Tags: google-analytics, backtracking, event-tracking

So,

I have a blog with a "demo button" with leads the user to a sign up page.

On sign up page, the user fill the general entries. Then he is brought to a payment page to enter his card details. and then from there he is taken to a confirmation page.

Now, I want to track every page. Basically, whether any user coming from a blog becomes a user or atleast how far he goes before closing the tab

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about page tracking and is not programing related.  may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use Enhanced E-Commerce Tracking.

The EEC in [Google Analytics lets you assign step numbers to the various steps in a checkout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout-process). It then creates a custom funnel report (remember that EEC must be enabled and configured not just in your code, but also in your view settings) that show how many users completed the checkout and how many dropped of at each step.